# robots.txt запрет индексации переменных

Tags: php, поисковые-системы, robots.txt

На сайте работает ЧПУ, но гугль всеравно лезит сканировать ссылки типа /index.php?variable=value. От куда он хавает ссылки эти даже ума не приложу. Ставил header location на случай если в урле присутствует знак "?". Переадресация работает и по сей день, но это не есть хорошо для сайта, т.к. поисковик лезет индексировать битые ссылки вместо того чтобы индексировать то что ему говорят...

Короче ближе к сути. Как составить правильный запрет на индексацию всего что находится после **.php?**

Следующее решение будет верным?

*Disallow: /index.php**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я как-то делал что-то вроде:

```
Disallow: /profile.php?username=*
```

Работало корректно, на сколько помню :)

Comment: попробую, но мне вообще нужно все вырубить после .php

Comment: Вообще на сколько я помню в robots.txt должны поддерживаться полностью регулярки.

Comment: Пока попробую своим примером, сейчас отправлю , бота схавать новый robots, будет видно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /*?твоя переменная* 
ну или
Disallow: /*.php // запретить индексацию всех php файлов встреченных в url
```